# Can I embed nearly any font in my Windows application, provided it's only installed during execution of the application?

Tags: windows, winapi, fonts

Most fonts provided with Windows + Office have at least a "Print & Preview embedding allowed" status.

Is it therefore allowed to bundle these fonts inside a Windows application, and to have that application install these fonts temporarily during execution, without getting into any legal trouble?

The fonts would only be used for the GUI, not to generate any documents.

There are lots of free fonts out there too, but it'd be nice to know if no restrictions existed with the Windows fonts, provided they're temporarily installed (AddFontResource).

Comment: You should definitely check with the font vendor before doing this. Preview & Print embedding applies to embedding the font into *documents*, not bundling with/embedding into applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with most types of software, font files are licensed, rather than sold. Licenses that govern the use of fonts vary from vendor to vendor but in general most licenses, including those covering the fonts Microsoft supplies with applications and Windows, do not allow the fonts to be embedded within applications or otherwise redistributed. Therefore, as a developer it is your responsibility to ensure that you have the required license rights for any font you embed within an application or otherwise redistribute.

This is from Windows MSDN site. You can find the page here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx

So it seems that you will need to get an open license 'shareware' style font. Another solution that I have used it the past is to create your own font. The site that I used was http://fontstruct.com/ which has a web tool to allow you to style your own font, it is free, plus there are some user created fonts that have an open license that you should be able to use - but be sure to check before hand.

Comment: If you don't want to pay for fonts and have some freedom design-wise, you can also check out Google Fonts; they have a pretty good selection and they are free to use in just about any way you can imagine. But if you have a specific requirement (i.e. one of the fonts bundled with Windows or Office, etc.) you might have a difficult time finding a replacement.